# WPF How to allow all treeview items to have the same Combobox associated with each item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, treeview

I have hit a pain point in regards to my WPF application, what i am ideally trying to achive here is for a treeview with child items to have a combobox next to each item, and in this combobox to have 3 text values. Such as

**ParentItem1**  Drop down ComboBox with 3 items
   *ChildItem1* Drop down ComboBox with 3 items
   *ChildItem2* Drop down ComboBox with 3 items
**ParentItem2** Drop down ComboBox with 3 items
   *ChildItem1* Drop down ComboBox with 3 items
   *ChildItem2* Drop down ComboBox with 3 items
   *ChildItem3* Drop down ComboBox with 3 items

I have fortunately gotten as far as listing some dummy data for the treeview and having a combobox presented, but unfortunately the 3 values do not show. i am using MVVM pattern here where i am binding my data to a viewmodel and vice-versa. here is the code i have so far:

**Xaml code:**

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="servicesKey" DataType="{x:Type src:Service}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,10,0,0" />
            <ComboBox Name="cmbStatusList" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding StateList}"
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                      SelectionChanged="cmb_SelectionChanged"
                      DisplayMemberPath="State"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      SelectedValuePath="StateID"
                      Width="150" 
                      Margin="20,0,0,0">
            <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                <Binding Path="NewIncident.StateID" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <validation:ComboBoxRules />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>

<TreeView Name="treeServices"
          ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceModel.Services}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource servicesKey}"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          Margin="0,0,10,10">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}"/>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

**Service View-Model**

```
public class ServiceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<Service> _services;
    public ServiceViewModel()
    {
        _services = new List<Service>();
    }

    public List<Service> Services
    {
        get { return _services; }
        set { _services = value; OnPropertyChanged("Services"); }
    }

    public override void OnChange()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Service : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Service(Service parent = null)
    {
        Children = new List<Service>();
    }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Service> Children { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public ServiceState StateID { get; set; }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Model**

```
    var statesmodel = _oakStatusProvider.GetServiceState()
        .Select(p => new Service()
        {
            StateID = p.StateID,
            State = p.State
        });

        _incidentViewModel.StateList = new List<Service>(statesmodel);
this.DataContext = _incidentViewModel;
```

**Get Service Method**

```
public List<ServiceDTO> GetServiceState()
{
    List<ServiceDTO> servicestatelist = new List<ServiceDTO>
    {
        new ServiceDTO { StateID = ServiceState.Normal, State = "Normal" },
        new ServiceDTO { StateID = ServiceState.Degraded, State = "Degraded" },
        new ServiceDTO { StateID = ServiceState.Critical, State = "Critical" },
    };
    return servicestatelist;
}
```

**States to be used in CMBbox**

```
public enum ServiceState
    {
        Normal = 0,
        Degraded = 10,
        Critical = 20,
    }
```

Result:
[Result combobox with treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVkqe.png)

**Binding directly to a Combobox works fine, seems to be DataTemplete messing things up?**

```
                                    <ComboBox Name="cmbSstatusList" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding StateList}"
                                  IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                                  SelectionChanged="cmb_SelectionChanged"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="State"
                                  IsEditable="True"
                                  IsReadOnly="True"
                                  SelectedValuePath="StateID"
                                  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="State" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}" 
                                  Width="150" 
                                  Height="45" 
                                  FontSize="15" >
                            <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                                <Binding Path="NewIncident.StateID" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
                                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                        <validation:ComboBoxRules />
                                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                </Binding>
                            </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                        </ComboBox>
```

Result:

[Working CMB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZcQb.png)

Thanks in advance for any help and assistance :). any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropdown control is not getting the StateList Property.

You need to name the Window screen and then perform Element Binding to get the StateList Binding work for the Dropdown control.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
        mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="Window1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
```

And for Combox box Control, use the ElementBinding to Bind the List.

```
 <ComboBox Name="cmbStatusList" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=DataContext.StateList}"
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                      DisplayMemberPath="State"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      IsReadOnly="True"
                      SelectedValuePath="StateID"
                      Width="150" 
                      Margin="20,0,0,0">
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: @S.Leu Check out the solution, let me know it is work for you ?

Comment: Thank you Satish, odd one that as i assumed that the ComboBox would work the same as if it was on its own, Seems to have sorted that one out.

Thank you again :)

Comment: Cheers, Glad was able to help you.